# DynamoDB causing module initialization error in Node/Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

For clarity, this takes place in a Node 6.10 AWS Lambda function.

Error:

`module initialization error: Error
    at Object.Service (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/service.js:24:28)
    at Object.features.constructor [as DynamoDB] (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/util.js:602:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/web.js:4:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)`

The module's initialisation:

`const aws = require('aws-sdk');
this.dynamoDb = new aws.DynamoDB();`

Not sure what to do here; missing something obvious?

Comment: Try excluding `aws-sdk` from your deployment package. It's already included in the Lambda environment anyway.

Comment: Had idea, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try,

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

//If you are running in Lambda you don't need below AWS.config section
AWS.config.update({
region: "REGION"
});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
```

and use 'docClient' to access DynamoDB functions.

For example,

```
  docClient.put(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to add item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err,null, 2));
    } else {
        callback(null, "Error while adding data:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
    }
});
```

Please find the sample I have created in my GitHub :- https://github.com/vnathv/DynamoDb-CRUD.git

Comment: If you're running in Lambda updating AWS.config is unnecessary

Comment: Yes I do agree. Edited the solution to include your comment. Thank you :)